# scala: how to iterate typesafe config list

Tags: scala

I am trying to iterate over the config List and it's giving me some error. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

**config**

```
test{
  header = [
    {
      name="col0"
      vale="aaa"
    }
    {
    name="col1"
    value="bbb"
    }
  ]
}
```

**code**

```scala
val headers:ConfigList  = ConfigFactory.load().getList("test.header")

    headers.forEach{header:Config =>
      val name = header.getString("name")
      println(name)
    }
```

**Error**

```
Error:(32, 35) type mismatch;
 found   : com.typesafe.config.Config => Unit
 required: java.util.function.Consumer[_ >: com.typesafe.config.ConfigValue]
    headers.forEach{header:Config =>
```

Comment: Which is your **Scala** version? are you open to using other libraries?

Comment: I am using  `2.11.8` I could use libraries.. but this is just small part of application, so would be nice if I can avoid it. I just need this list to converted into list of maps. I mean maps of `name`, `value` pair.

Comment: So the problem is that `ConfigList` is a **Java** class that expects a **Java** `Consumer` which is not related to a **Scala** `Function`.  - You have four alternatives, constructing the `Consumer` manually. - Using the [**Scala-Java8-Compat** library](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) that will provide an extension method that does the precious for you. - Upgrading to **Scala** `2.12` which provides SAMs which will make the conversion automatically. - Use [**Pureconfig**](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig) to parse that config into a case class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Luis said, Functions in Scala 2.11.x do are not compiled to Java Functions. And since they are not Java Functions, they can not be converted to `Consumer` via SAM.

And so, You will need to explicitly provide a `Cosumer`.

Also, with `getList("...")` you get a `ConfigList` which can be used to iterate over `ConfigValue` elements and not `Config`.

```scala
headers.forEach(new Consumer<ConfigValue> {
  override def accept(configValue: ConfigValue): Unit = {
    // Since you have ConfigValue... do whatever you want with it
    println(configValue.render())
  }
})
```

What you actually want to use is `getConfigList(...)`

```scala
val headers = ConfigFactory.load().getConfigList("test.header")

headers.forEach(new Consumer<Config> {
  override def accept(config: Config): Unit = {
    println(config.getString("name"))
  }
})
```

Comment: is there a way I can create a map `Map(col1 -> bbb, col0 -> aaa)`. currently I am using mutable map and populating in loop. was thinking if there is better way to do this

Comment: `headers.getConfigList("test.header").asScala.map(c => c.getString("name") -> c.getString("value")).toMap`